# Unable to connect Azure SQL from Report Builder

Tags: azure-sql-database, reportbuilder

I am unable to connect to Azure SQL and access my database from Report builder.

Getting following error:

[image]

I had enabled the access in Azure portal for the above IP mentioned. Still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to repro successfully, Make sure you specify the **Database Name explicitly** and try again.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am fix my issue. The above mentioned things I already implemented. Issue was of number of firewall rule exceeded to 128. After removing old rules, I am able to fix the issue and able to access the Azure SQL.

Thanks for your quick and detailed solution.